# Affine transformation of different sized polygons layer to equal area units

Tags: qgis, python, polygon, grass-gis, affine-transformation

I would like to transform a layer of polygons of different <del>size</del>area to become equal in area<del>size</del>. I have QGIS 2.18 and GRASS GIS 7 available and some basic Python knowledge. Does anyone have an idea of how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "same size"? Same geometry but at a different location? same area? Uploading a graphic might help.

Comment: All output polygons to have the same area? By distorting the shapes? How different in areas are the input polygons and what coordinate reference system are they in?